# How to detect outliers "among neighbouring values" of univariate data using standard python

Tags: python, python-3.7, outliers

I have a simple data-set that has 2 columns date/temperature.

I need some method to find outliers:
 1. In the temperature column
 2. Only w.r.t to some neighbouring values

What will be the best way to detect outliers w.r.t neighbouring values only?

I have tried coding up IQR, Mean/Median deviation etc but they prune out more values. I tried applying those methods to 10 values at a time but that ends up finding even more outliers than I expect.

Also I need to finally code it in standard python, so any hints on that will be useful.

Below are the functions from my class DataChecker that calculate IQR and use it to check outlier.

```
class DataChecker:
    class DateTemperature:
        def __init__(self, input_date, temperature):
            try:
                day, month, year = input_date.split('/')
                self._temperature_date = date(int(year), int(month), int(day))
            except ValueError:
                # Don't tolerate invalid date
                raise #TODO change to custom error 

            try:
                self._temperature = float(temperature)
            except (TypeError, ValueError):
                self._temperature = 0

        @property
        def date(self):
            return self._temperature_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

        @property
        def temperature(self):
            return self._temperature

    def __init__(self, input_date_temperature_values):
        self._date_temperature_values = []
        for date, temperature in input_date_temperature_values:
            try:
                self._date_temperature_values.append(self.DateTemperature(date, temperature))
            except ValueError:
                pass

        self._date_temperature_values.sort(key=lambda x:x.date)

        self._outlier_low, self._outlier_high = self._calculate_outlier_thresholds(self._date_temperature_values)

    def _is_value_outlier(self, temperature):
        if temperature < self._outlier_low or temperature > self._outlier_high:
            return True
        return False

    def _calculate_outlier_thresholds(self, data_temperature_values):
        temperature_values = sorted([dataTemperature.temperature for dataTemperature in data_temperature_values])
        median_index = len(temperature_values) // 2
        first_quartile = median(temperature_values[:median_index])
        third_quartile = median(temperature_values[median_index+1:])

        iqr = (third_quartile - first_quartile)

        # Tried with 1.5, 1.2, 2 etc
        low_iqr = first_quartile - 1.2*iqr
        high_iqr = third_quartile + 1.2*iqr

        # Trying mean/median deviation
        #mean_value = statistics.median(temperature_values)
        #std_dev = statistics.pstdev(temperature_values)
        #print(f'{mean_value} : {std_dev}')
        #low_iqr = mean_value - 2*std_dev
        #high_iqr = mean_value + 2*std_dev


        #print(low_iqr, ':', high_iqr)
        return low_iqr, high_iqr
```

Thanks!

Comment: Post the code achieved so far

Answer (score 0):

Standard Deviation: The standard deviation is a measure that is used to quantify the amount of variation or dispersion of a set of data values.

Mean: Mean is the sum of the sampled values divided by the number of items.

```
import numpy as np

def removeOutlier(data):
  data = np.array(data)
  mean = np.mean(data, axis=0)
  std = np.std(data, axis=0)
  final_list = [x for x in data if (x > mean - 2 * std)]
  final_list = [x for x in final_list if (x < mean + 2 * std)]
  return final_list
```

you can select the neighboring point and put it in a list then if you pass it through this function you'll get outlier free list.